# PHP PDO Select Query Missing Initial Space Character

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm finding that my first record in a result is missing the first space character when querying an SQLite and ODBC database with PHP's PDO wrapper. As an example, this is one of the results I'm seeing:

```
['Howdo I reset my password?','How do I change the email address registered to my account?']
```

I've seen this result when working with multiple types of database and PDO. Has anyone seen this as well?

I'm running on PHP 7.2.1. I'm using the following code:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:../ncw.db"); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$q = $db->prepare('SELECT title FROM Article WHERE category LIKE :value');
$q->execute(array('value' => '%' . $category . '%'));
$r  = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($r as $row){
    $a[] = "'" . $row['title'] . "'";
};
echo '[' . implode(",",$a) . ']';
$db = null;
```

If I use var_dump, I get the following results:

```
array(1){ ["title"]=> string(27) "How do I reset my password?" } array(1) { ["title"]=> string(59) "How do I change the email address registered to my account?" }
```

Comment: It looks like the information in your database is missing a space. And you should not manually build json, instead use `json_encode()`.

Comment: No, the actual record does have a space, and I'm not actually building out JSON in this particular circumstance.

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump($row);` in the loop? What is the result of that?

Comment: When I use var_dump, I get the following: array(1){ ["title"]=> string(27) "How do I reset my password?" } array(1) { ["title"]=> string(59) "How do I change the email address registered to my account?" }

Comment: Then the space *is* there. It just it's probably not a good old ['SPACE' U+0020](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm) but something else. You can verify that with e.g. [bin2hex()](http://php.net/bin2hex).

Comment: So the problem is not with PDO / SQLite.

Comment: I don't see what **space** are you looking for? There is no leading space in any samples you've posted.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. I reviewed the character encoding of the result, and found it was ASCII, which I assume is related to the encoding of the text in the database itself. I set the character set as USASCII, and it resolved the issue:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=USASCII');
```

Comment: It's really strange that a library or tool defaults to 7-bit US-ASCII in 2018. Are you sure it isn't UTF-8 instead? Also, I can't figure out how this could affect U+0020 but not everything else. What did `bin2hex()` reveal, BTW?